# Angular: Tabkey Press not Populating fields

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, I have a component which contains some basic fields and dropdown  menu.When I select anything from dropdown using tab key the other related field are not getting populated,But it works with mouse click.

receipt-creation.component.ts

```
    populateItems(event: any, obj) {
    this.receiptForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      const dirty = this.isFormDirty(this.receiptForm);
      if (dirty) {
        this.unsavedChanges = true;
      }
    });
    this.receiptLineItems = obj.itemList; // obj.itemList contain the values related to selected item
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.updateSubtotal(); // this function caluclate the total based on the item selected from the dropdown
  }
```

receipt-creation.component.html

```
<add-new-row
      [addNewText]="INVOICE_CONSTS.ADD_LINE_ITEM"
      [canAutoAddNewRow]="false"
      [checkPristine]="true"
      [type]="'receipt'"
      [data]="lineItemsMetaData"
      [form]="receiptCreationForm"
      [triggerExtraAddNewKey]="true"
      [itemList]="receiptLineItems"
      (changeItemEvent)="populateItems($event, receiptCreationForm)"
      (keydown.enter)="preventFormSubmission($event)"
 ></add-new-row>
```

With event.preventDefault() the fields gets populated, but I want the default behaviour of tab key to be working.

Comment: It may cause by your external lib. The event should be trigger. Eg. this plain dropdown: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Comment: Hey @paranaaan, thanks for your response, i'll look into my external lib.